# Python: Regex: Detecting hyphenated names and non-hyphenated names with one regex

Tags: python, regex, capturing-group

I need to extract people's names from a really long string.

Their names are in this format: LAST, FIRST.

Some of these people have hyphenated names. Some don't.

**My attempt with a smaller string:**

Input:

```
import re
text = 'Smith-Jones, Robert&Epson, Robert'
pattern = r'[A-Za-z]+(-[A-Za-z]+)?,\sRobert'
print re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Expected output:

```
['Smith-Jones, Robert', 'Epson, Robert']
```

Actual output:

```
['-Jones', '']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
import re
text = 'Smith-Jones, Robert&Epson, Robert'
pattern = r'[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)?,\sRobert'
print re.findall(pattern, text)
# => ['Smith-Jones, Robert', 'Epson, Robert']
```

Just make the capturing group non-capturing. The thing is that `findall` returns capture group values if they are specified in the regex pattern. So, the best way to solve this in this pattern is just replace `(...)?` with `(?:...)?`.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/pAXhgY)

Comment: Just in case there are entries where space before `Robert` is missing, you may add a `*` quantifier after `\s` to match 0 or more occurrences: `r'[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)?,\s*Robert'`.